# Generate thumbnail of video file dropzone.js

Tags: dropzone.js

I had put thumbnailWidth and thumbnailHeight in dropzone configuration but not getting thumbnail for video that I uploaded . Can someone tell me do dropzone.js automatically generates video thumbnails?

Comment: Tried the same. But, thumbnail preview is not available for videos.